# Power BI Not Sorting Dates Correctly

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm sorting data by Date Hierarchy (Day), and while the days appear in order, the months are out of order. So instead of displaying 11/28, 11/29,11/30, 12/1 it is displaying incorrectly ordered JUST by the day - so I see 12/1, 11/28,11/29 etc. Nothing I do can seem to sort it correctly.

Comment: Can you try with date 12/5, 11/3, 11/15? I don't think its ordering using Day.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is ordering by Month. Clear all other sort from other columns and try sorting. If not done try indexing based on separated day month and year.